# forms of the Romberg Method equation

Tags: integration, analysis, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

My teacher wrote the this equation for the Romberg method

$
I_{j,k}=\frac{4^j I_{j-1/k+1}-I_{j-1/k}}{4^j-1}
$

Is this the right equation? Most the equations I looked at online for the Romberg equation look different; for example, see [Romberg Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg's_method) and [Romberg Method](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~tkolokol/classes/1500/romberg.pdf)

Comment: The subscripts in this formula seems wrong. $k$ in the formula means  the times of extrapolation. So the subscripts in the RHS should be $k$ and $k-1$.

Comment: Lion, I don't understand what you mean could you please rewrite the equation in the write form.

Comment: JLOLOJ, I add an answer in detail. And you can find the explanation of the formula in some references about numerical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the Romberg's method can be described as
$$
T_m^k=\frac{4^m T_{m-1}^k-T_{m-1}^{k-1}}{4^m-1}
$$
where $T_m^k$ means the quadrature result with $k$ times dichotomies and $m$ times extrapolations. Let the integral interval is $[a,b]$, for example, $T_0^0$ means the result of the quadrature with step $b-a$. $T^1_0$ means the result with step $\frac{b-a}{2}$. And $T_1^0$ means the extrapolation result that linear combination of $T_0^0$ and $T_0^1$ (See Richardson extrapolation). So, in your shown formula, the subscripts of $k$ seems wrong because linear combination of $k+1$ and $k$ dichotomy results gives a $k+1$ dichotomy result not a $k$ one.

Comment: Does this work too? $$
T_m^k=\frac{4^m T_{m-1}^{k+1}-T_{m-1}^{k}}{4^m-1}
$$

Comment: No. This is what shown in your question. As I explain in my answer, linear combination of $k+1$ and $k$ dichotomy results gives a $k+1$ dichotomy result not a $k$ one. So if you want to keep the RHS of the formula, the LHS should be $T_m^{k+1}$.

Comment: I have an exam tomorrow which equation should I use then?

Comment: The one I shown in my answer.